# Finding someone in Amsterdam Airport

Tags: air-travel, airports, ams

Where is a good place to meet someone in the Amsterdam airport.  We are arriving from 2 different countries (USA and S. Africa).

Comment: Looks like the airport has an officially designated [meeting point](https://www.schiphol.nl/Travellers/ToFromSchipholNieuw/CollectingBringing/MeetingPoint1.htm), with a board that can display your messages when you send it a text.

Comment: @NateEldridge that's a great answer if both travelers are able to pass through immigration control -- Schiphol plaza is the concourse above the train station, completely outside the secured area of the airport. If the travelers are hoping to meet while in transit, they may want or need to make other arrangements.

Answer (score 7):

Is Amsterdam your final destination? If so, right after you collect your bags you will be at the Schiphol Plaza - which is like a shopping area / train + bus station.

This plaza is a vast courtyard and contains many shops, the main ticket station for the rail systems; the kiosks where you can buy transit tickets, the entrances to the trains (escalators going down to the basement) and where the official meeting point (white and red painted building) is located.

It is hard to miss as you naturally end up in this area (if you are not being picked up by transportation); of course you are free to pick any place to meet here - the official meeting point stands out from the crowd, but you can pick another reference point; such as the train ticket counters.

If you are both transiting in Schiphol and are looking to meet airside; the easiest place is this Mediterranean Sandwich Bar; it is recognizable by the large green metalwork/decor. It is located at the escalators that lead up to Lounge 1, next to a yellow information booth, a Starbucks and the flight information displays.  You can't miss it since it is one of the unique looking shops in the airport (the others all kind of blend into the decor).

[image: Mediterranean Sandwich Bar]
Image courtesy a_marga/flickr

This [360 panorama](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/6298144608920335490?pid=6298144608920335490&oid=113049602242981844531) gives a better idea of the location of the store.

Comment: There are several groups of ticket machines. If you make it to the train station, you might as well use the official meeting point, which is very near.

Comment: (-1) It's not a big deal, just a small edit to make but you really ought to take my earlier remark into account. There are three groups of ticket machines that are not in clear sight of each other, that's potentially confusing and not very good advice. If you really don't like the official meeting point (it's not difficult to find once you know to look for it) then any brand/landmark in this general area (HEMA food, news kiosk, NS ticket *desk*...) would be better.

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Yes Amsterdam is my final destination.